# YouTube Video Responsive with Chapter Stops

Tags: javascript, php, video, responsive-design, youtube

I need to put a bunch of YouTube videos with Chapter Stops, like the link above, into a responsive website and make it responsive.

I know how to make a YouTube video responsive using the below code.

```
<style type="text/css">
.video-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="video-container">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/o_Qc3XJJuyI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

But since this contains Chapter Stops I am not sure where to start, how do I use the code ABOVE with the code BELOW to make BOTH the video and Chapter Stops responsive?

Here is my code.

```
<h1>A Closer Look at The Value of MRIs</h1>

<!--CHAPTER VIDEO-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mymsaa.org/chapters/chapter_marker_player3.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mymsaa.org/chapters/odd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mymsaa.org/chapters/chapter_marker_player3.js"></script>

<div id="iframe-session-player"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
ChapterMarkerPlayer.insert({
  container: 'iframe-session-player',
  videoId: 'o_Qc3XJJuyI',
  width: 560,
// BEGIN_INCLUDE(define_chapters)
  chapters: {
    11: 'Introduction/Part 1. Getting an MRI',
    700: 'Part 2. Learning from a Neurologist',
    1782: 'Part 3. MSAAs MRI Programs',

  }
// END_INCLUDE(define_chapters)
});
</script>
<!--CHAPTER VIDEO-->

<p>The use of magnetic resonance imaging (MRI) plays an important role in diagnosing multiple sclerosis, tracking disease progression, and evaluating the effectiveness of prescribed therapy. This three-part program features interviews with an MS patient describing her experience undergoing an MRI exam, a noted neurologist explaining the value of an MRI, and a representative of MSAA discussing the organization's two MRI financial assistance programs.</p>
```

Comment: I don't think that the responsive code you showed for the youtube video will work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s38awp3n/).

Hopefully that will help lead you into the right direction regarding responsiveness.

Wrap everything in a container that you wish to make responsive, give everything within that container a width of 100%, and then make adjustments to the container's iframe where necessary through media queries.

```
.responsive{
    width:80%;
    margin:0px auto;
}

.responsive iframe {
    height:300px;
}
@media(min-width:768px){
    .responsive iframe {
         height:450px;   
    }
}
@media(min-width:992px){
    .responsive iframe{
         height:550px;   
    }
}
@media(min-width:1200px){
     .responsive iframe {
         height:660px;   
     }
}
```